# Just want to know 2 simple question?

Tags: table, version

1. When the table with name **sales_flat_order** first introduced in **Magento** 
   & in which version ?
2. When the table with name **log_visitor** first introduced in **Magento** 
   & in which version ?

Answer (score 2):

sales_flat_order was added in 1.4 version.

log_visitor has been there since the beginning of time